# pointer offset doesnt work in memset?

Tags: c, memset

Plain C, on Windows 7 & HP machine.

```
int main(void) {

    unsigned int a =  4294967295;
    unsigned int *b = &a;

    printf("before val: '%u'\n", *b); // expect 4294967295, got 4294967295

    memset(b+2, 0, 1);

    printf("after val: '%u'\n", *b);
    // little endian          4th      3rd     2nd       1st
    // expect 4278255615 - 11111111 00000000 11111111 11111111
    // got    4294967295 - 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111

    return 0;

}
```

I want to set the third byte of the integer to 0x0, but is remains the same. Any ideas? Thank you.

On my machine, int is 32 bits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pointer addition/subtraction does not move by only one byte - it moves by the size of the type of the object being pointed to.

That is to say (assuming 4-byte integers),

```
int *p = 0x00004
int *q = p+1;
assert(q == 0x00008)
```

Basically, it's the same as if you used the index of operator:

```
int *q = &p[1]
```

If you want to increment a pointer by one, cast it to a `unsigned char *`. The way you did it, you were overwriting memory that was not part of the variable `a` and possibly overwriting existing data for something else.

Comment: Actually, you can't assume anything about `(int*)0 + 1` except that it is `!= 0`, since the null pointer may be handled specially.

Comment: @larsmans bah humbug :P You can't assume NULL is zero either :P But I changed my post. Cheers, mate.

Comment: Right, it increments by the size of of the type. A complete goof. Thank you. Accept in a minute.

Comment: You can assume that `0`, in a pointer context, is the null pointer. http://c-faq.com/null/null2.html (But +1.)

Answer (score 2):

The b+2 meens in fact a displacement of two int not two bytes.

```
 unsigned int *b = &a;
 memset(b+2, 0, 1);
```

In fact you want to modify the third byte

```
 unsigned int *b = &a;
 memset( ((char*)b)+2, 0, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

int is only guaranteed to be at least two bytes, so if you want to set the third byte you should use a long int (or uint32_t).  Anyway, I'd do it using the bitwise and operator

```
unsigned long a = 4294967293;
/* regular code */
a &= 0xFFFF00FF;
```